# Reduce Rails Passenger Thread Counts

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

My host account is limited to 300 processes. As I turn on my rail app, it ate up 100 process immidiately. Does anyone know how to reduce "Passenger Core" and Passenger process count?

This is my nginx config:

```
env GEM_HOME=/home/user/gems;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  256;        # default 1024
}

http {
    access_log  /home/user/logs/user/access_myapp.log  combined;
    error_log   /home/user/logs/user/error_myapp.log   crit;

    include         mime.types;
    passenger_root  /home/user/gems/gems/passenger-5.0.30;
    passenger_ruby  /home/user/bin/ruby;
    sendfile        on;

    passenger_max_instances_per_app  1;
    rails_spawn_method               conservative;
    passenger_max_pool_size 1;      # default 2

    server {
        listen             xxx;
        passenger_enabled  on;
        root               /home/user/myapp/public;
        server_name        localhost;
        rails_env          production;

        location ~* ^/assets/ {
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;

            add_header Last-Modified "";
            add_header ETag "";
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

This is output of the ps list: http://pastebin.com/0DcrmxC4

Thanks

Comment: Find a more reasonable hosting provider?

Comment: The price of being cheap, ssd hosting for $10/mth

Comment: You can do better than that, even for $10!